# print collections(map) of cassandra using php

Tags: php, cassandra, cql

After querying the Cassandra database for a particular record using php, I want to print the row. The row has one column of type map. the map has text datatype for both key and value.

How to print this map type using printf command of php?

Comment: what you have tried ?